# Using Embedded Style Resources With LESS

Tags: asp.net, less, embedded-resource

I was wondering if it's possible to include .less files that are from an embedded resource as @import or some other manner.

Currently we have all styles compiled into a resource DLL.  It would be nice to add the resource DLL and then using @import statements, import the style information into the active .less file, that's in a project unrelated to the resource DLL.

I looked at the dotless source code and there does seem to be some code to import DLL resources by name. The lack of documentation, and my lack of understanding of the source lead me to a mental dead end.

[dotless Embedded Resource Reference](https://github.com/dotless/dotless/pull/201)

Ideally it would be nice to do this without a plugin. Currently, Visual Studio 2013 packages Mad Kristensen's Web Essentials, which includes a less compiler in the IDE.  Looking through the source for it on git hub I couldn't find any references to extending the built-in compiler.

[Web Essentials 2013](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013)

So long story short, has anyone done this?

Comment: I haven't tried the dotLess embedded resource syntax, but my first instinct would be to write a simple IHttpHandler and have that one get the resource, call dotless (if you want to return css instead of less) and write that to the response. Unless you count that as a plugin.

Comment: @Mark Problem is, it would only support one embedded resource. (or one less file) What I am looking for is being able to compose using the import statement inside less files with embedded resources. Good thought though.